# How to import files to individual posts of a custom type

Tags: custom-post-types, attachments, import

I'm very inexperienced in WP, so I may have some fundamental misunderstandings - definitely open to alternative approaches if this one is crazy!

I have a collection of several hundred files, split into two groups.  One is 'Documents', which is all PDFs.  The other is 'Downloads', which is an assortment of random file types.

I need to insert these into a WP site in a way that they would be searchable, listable, categorizable, etc. - so, my initial instinct is to make a custom post type for Documents and one for Downloads, and then attach each file to an individual 'post', which will have all the features I was looking for.  However, none of the documentation or plugins I can find seem to help with going from files to discrete posts.  Is that because it's a completely wrong idea, or if not, how can I go about completing it?

Comment: You already have a custom post type to handle files. It's the attachment post_type. If you need you can add custom fields to the attachment and create custom libraries inside Dashboard or through page templates.

Comment: @RicardoBRGWeb as an answer please :)

Comment: @Rarst I don't thing it is really an answer to his question. I am just making a sugestion :). The answer would be more complex...